# Amazon Word Publication File to CMYK

Tags: cmyk, microsoft-word

I recently published a short story on Amazon and only the pink color in the text and in the photo were off. They were too dull. Amazon said to convert their template into CMYK colors. Most of what I have read about CMYK is for images, is there a way to convert text color and image on only one color?

Thank you for the help!

Joshua

Comment: MS Word doesn't support CMYK.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *really* broad question which off-hand would seem to take **a lot** of explaining to answer for someone unfamiliar with the printing process to competently grasp everything which takes place. It's *not* "rocket science" but it's not always easy for individuals to grasp right away either.

First.... **Microsoft Word does not support CMYK color**. Microsoft Word is not designed for commercial printing and has **zero** support for CMYK color. ***You just can't use Word if you need a CMYK file.***

That being posted, Word can be saved as a PDF... and if you have Adobe Acrobat you may be able to covert the resulting **PDF** to CMYK color.

All this is **very general** and broad to help and explain things. Truth of the matter is, you may be best hiring someone who knows all this stuff to convert your file for you. It *could* be a simple matter for a knowledgable person while being far more confusing to someone with no experience and looking for a quality product, it's difficult to say for certain without seeing the files.

---

Additional information..... CMYK is *not* "for images". CMYK is for *everything*. A printing press holds 4 inks.. Cyan, Magenta, Yellow and Black... from those 4 inks millions of colors are created by printing the inks in small dots next to each other so the human eye sees a single color.

[image]

It doesn't matter if the color is applied to text, photos, illustrations, etc. If it's color, this is how the color is created in CMYK process printing.

It is customarily a *bad idea* to use color on small type. Small type is often best set as just black so it remains solid and readable.

If you have text set in a color, you need to ensure that color is built using a CMYK values. In other words 100%C, 0%M, 100%Y, and 0%K will make a green.... and so on. What specific percentages work in your case is entirely up to you.

In **addition** to the use standard colors, all images (photos AND illustrations) should also be in CMYK color mode. To edit an image's color mode you need image editing software such as Adobe Photoshop or The Gimp, etc.